# rails creating a new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  #validate :username ,:first_name ,:last_name ,:email ,:password ,:phone ,:location ,:require => true
#  validates :username,:require => true
  validates :username, :presence => true
  has_many :ads 

  #validates :phone , :presence => true
  attr_accessor :password,:password_confirmation
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  attr_protected :hashed_password ,:salt
```

## users_controller

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = 'User successfully created.'
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action => 'index'
    end
  end
  def new
    if session[:user_id]
      flash[:notice] = "You have already registered"
      redirect_to(:controller => 'main',:action => 'index')
    end
    @user = User.new

  end
  alias :register :new
```

## registration_form

```
            <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
                <%= f.error_messages %>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                        <%= f.label :first_name %>
                </th>
                <td>
                        <%= f.text_field :first_name ,:placeholder => 'Please enter your real name.' %><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                        <%= f.label :last_name %>
                </th>
                <td>
                        <%= f.text_field :last_name ,:placeholder => 'Please enter your real name.' %><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <%= f.label :username  %>

                </th>
                <td>
                    <%= f.text_field :username ,:placeholder => 'Enter your username here'%>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
            <%= f.label :email%>            
                </th>
                <td>
                <%= f.text_field :email ,:placeholder => 'sample@sample.com'  %><br/>       
                </td>
            </tr>

            <% if !session[:user_id] %>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                            <%= f.label :password %>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                            <%= f.password_field :password  ,:placeholder => 'EnterPassword' %><br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                            <%= f.label :password_confirmation,'Confirm Password' %>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                            <%= f.password_field  :password_confirmation  ,:placeholder => 'Confirm password' %><br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>


            <tr>
                <th>
                        <%= f.label :phone %>
                </th>
                <td>
                        <%= f.text_field :phone  ,:placeholder => '09351270000' %><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                        <%= f.label :location %>
                </th>
                <td>
                        <%= f.text_field :location  ,:placeholder => 'Your address' %><br/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td></td>   <td>    <%= f.submit !session[:user_id] ? 'Register' : 'Save changes',:class => 'button',:style => 'height:50px' %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <% end %>
```

## doubt

when i am logging in and updating user information using the same form its working fine , but when i am creating new user , i am redirected to users/index , while i am supposed to be registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically means that the @user.save fails.  There can be many reasons for this, it is hard to tell exactly what this is, since you don't give any error messages. The most probable case, I think, you are running into now is that you are trying to set a field (column of the user model) which is not accessible by the `attr_accessible` field.

Since you have commented that line out you are telling rails that there exists no fields in the user model which can be mass assigned. This is what happens when you call `User.create(params[:user])`

So to fix you problem now, try uncommenting your `attr_accessible` and add all the fields you need to set a user. In your case this would be:

```
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :password, :phone, :location
```

I suggest you find some information on what attr_accessible and these others do. It is handy to know how these work.

Comment: i set attr_protected as :hashed_password and salt , doesnt that make everything else accessible ??